# Add a description to a data frame or RMD object

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

The internat datasets of R give some brief explanation of its structure, background and content. For example:

```
?mtcars
```

gives me all the background I need to make sense of the data. is it possible to do the same with your own data-frames when you save them as an RMD? it would be really useful when I am collaborating with others.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom attribute to the object that describes it. It'll get saved with the object and can be accessed using `attr`

```
data("iris")
i1 <- iris
attributes(i1)
# $names
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $row.names
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
# [25]  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
# [49]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
# [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
# [97]  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
# [121] 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
# [145] 145 146 147 148 149 150

attr(i1,'desc') <- 'Sample data on flowers'
attributes(i1)
# $names
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $row.names
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
# [25]  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
# [49]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
# [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
# [97]  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
# [121] 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
# [145] 145 146 147 148 149 150
# 
# $desc
# [1] "Sample data on flowers"

attr(i1,'desc')
# [1] "Sample data on flowers"
```